# How to handle development of nested graph python libraries

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

Imagine I have:

- Library Z
- Library Y, which depends on Library Z
- Application A, which depends on Library Y

To fully test out changes to Library Z, I'd like to run the tests of Application A with any [Development releases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#developmental-releases) of Library Z.

To do this I can set up Library Z to publish packages to some package index for development releases under the versioning scheme `{major}.{minor}.{micro}.dev{build}`, then have Library Y specify it's dependency range for Library Z as `>={major},<{major+1}` for instance and use `pip install --pre ...` on Application A to ensure the Development releases of Library Z are picked up.

This all works fine, until we have > 1 maintainer of Library Z making changes, likely in different `git` branches, and effectively competing on the `{build}` number. Wondering how folks have solved this problem?

This problem gets potentially worse as well if in Application A you are also in a situation where > 1 maintainer are making changes and not everyone wants to ingest the Development release, so ensure the `--pre` flag is optionally passed and ideally synced up with just the dependency in question (possible with `poetry` via the more granular `allow-prereleases` flag, see docs [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#expanded-dependency-specification-syntax)).

---

Editable installs are likely considered out of scope, this set up is a trivial case. In reality this dependency graph could be deeper, and is often pared with Docker to make it commercially viable when pared with C dependencies so the complexity of hooking up volume mounts very hard. Also the user developing Library Z, may be different than the person testing Application A.

Whilst I used `pip` in the examples here, in reality our system uses `poetry` (and `pip` in places).

Comment: Can you point the packages to version control commit hashes r tags instead of depending on versioning? As a plus: no need to worry about having to publish [competing] pre-release versions in any package index. (.e.g.: pip install git+https://github.com/django/django.git@45dfb3641aa4d9828a7c5448d11aa67c7cbd7966 )

Comment: This is effectively the solution we currently use but manually updating references in consuming libraries/applications doesn't scale super well so looking for a semi-automated approach. Effectively what I think I'm looking for is a multi-tenant version of nightly builds, as in our company we publish a development release on every commit and may want to consume that the same day (likely within minutes of it being published).

Answer (score 0):

[given the information exchanged in the comments...] Then version control branches should do. If you agree that a certain branch in lib Z will have the new features app A needs for the purposes of build W, just keeping that branch updated won´t require any changes on the configuration of W, and no package building: at this point you are down to being able to switch the requirement list (and the pointers to each branch) on the build process of A.

I don't know how Poetry could handle this, but using a `setup.py` file it should be trivial: just read different text files listing the requirements (with pointers to specific GIT branches or Tags), based on a system-variable or other configuration you can easily change for the build. Since setup.py are plain Python code file, one can just use `if` statements along with `os.environ` to check environment variables, and read the contents of `requirements_setup_W.txt` to feed the `install_requires` parameter of the call to `setup`.

Either way, you are saying each package might have more than one state of "pre-release", which would be interesting for different builds - I think managing that through branches in the version control would be better than uploading several differing packages for a repository. *or* maybe, change the uploaded package **name** for each finality. So, you could have a package named `libZ_setupW` on the local pypi (and rotate the requirements by code on setup.py . (again, the *main* pain point of poetry is trashing executable code expecting all build needs can be represented by config files: they can't. I just looked around, and there seems to be no "poetry pre-build hook", which could be used to rename (or dynamically rewrite) your pyproject.toml according to the desired setup. One could add a script to do just that, but it would need to be called manually before calling `poetry install`)